# How to use union with a query of view itself?

Tags: views

I have a table that have 2 types of data:

- first type is '1'
- second type is '2'

And I want to get 3 records of both by union so,
I want to know that how to get 3 records of both types from one table at a time
so it is possible by union with itself so i want to add union with my views content.

How to get query of view and alter it and where I put this query in Drupal 7 but I have no one module for this data.

Answer (score 1):

You can look here (https://drupal.org/node/409808) for information on creating custom sql statements in a View.